# Transfer money using JSON

Tags: php, json

I worked on api-transfer-money for form located on the profile page. Everything was working, and all of a sudden my api file started to show me error "you don't have this account id", and I can't figure out why.

clients.json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "peterjak": {
      "name": "Peter", 
      "accounts": {
        "5c7072a835c3b": {
          "balance": 1000, 
          "name": "Savings"
        }, 
        "5c7696db0745b": {
          "balance": 2000, 
          "name": "University"
        }
      }, 
      "nikajak": {
        "name": "nika", 
        "accounts": {
          "5c7000098525e": {
            "balance": 500
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

api-transfer-money.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$sSender = $_SESSION['sUserId'];

$sData = file_get_contents('../data/clients.json');
$jData = json_decode($sData);

$idRecipient = $_POST['txtToAccountId'];
$idSender = $_POST['txtFromAccountId'];

$sBalanceSender = $jData
    ->data
    ->$sSender
    ->accounts->{$idSender}->balance;

if ($sBalanceSender < $iAmount) {
    sendResponse(-1, __LINE__, 'you are too poor');
}
$sSenderAccounts = $jData
    ->data
    ->$sSender->accounts;
$sSenderAccountsList = array_keys($sSenderAccounts);
$sRecipientAccounts = $jData
    ->data
    ->$sRecipient->accounts;
$sRecipientAccountsList = array_keys($sRecipientAccounts);

if (!in_array($idSender, $sSenderAccountsList)) {
    sendResponse(-1, __LINE__, 'You dont have this account id');
}

if (!in_array($idRecipient, $sRecipientAccountsList)) {
    sendResponse(-1, __LINE__, 'Recipients account id not found');
}

$jData
    ->data
    ->$sRecipient
    ->accounts->{$idRecipient}->balance += $iAmount;

// Take money from the logged user
$jData
    ->data
    ->$sSender
    ->accounts->{$idSender}->balance -= $iAmount;

$sData = json_encode($jData);
if ($sData == null) {
    sendResponse(0, __LINE__);
}
file_put_contents('../data/clients.json', $sData);

function sendResponse($iStatus, $iLineNumber, $sMessage) {
    echo '{"status":' . $iStatus . ', "code":' . $iLineNumber . ',"message":"' . $sMessage . '"}';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this "5c7072a835c3b" is not the id? id : ""5c7072a835c3b""

Comment: FYI, it's simpler and more efficient to do `if(!isset($sSenderAccounts[$idSender]))` than `in_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$sRecipientAccounts` and `$sSenderAccounts` are objects, not arrays, so you can't use `array_keys()` to get the property names.

You can use `get_object_vars()` to get an associative array of property names and values, and then use `array_keys()` on this. But it would be simpler to just check whether the specified property exists directly.

```
$sSenderAccounts = $jData->data->$sSender->accounts;
$sRecipientAccounts = $jData->data->$sRecipient->accounts;

if(!isset($sSenderAccounts->{$idSender})){
    sendResponse( -1, __LINE__, 'You dont have this account id'); 
}

if(!isset($sRecipientAccounts->{$idRecipient})){
    sendResponse( -1, __LINE__, 'Recipients account id not found'); 
}
```